# Swift/iOS: Extremely Odd Behavior of NSDateComponent on the 30th

Tags: ios, date, swift, nsdateformatter

I see lots of "Odd behavior" posts about the iOS calendar, but this one doesn't seem to be in there, so I'll add this to the pile.

I have a class that, amongst other things, calculates the difference between two dates, and displays them as a period of months, days and years.

I need to go back and test this in ObjC, but I don't think it happens there, as this is a rewrite of a very old app that I wrote a few years ago in C.

Now, today being June 30, I was writing up unit tests, and noticed that the calendar gave the same count for two different dates.

To be exact, it says that December 30, 2012 to June 30, 2014 is 1 year and six months exactly.

I also says that December 31, 2012 to June 30, 2014 is 1 year and six months. EXACTLY. It should be 1 year, five months and 30 days (I believe).

In any case, both dates should not create the same time interval.

Here's the code I'm using. I can't see anything I'm doing wrong. Any clues?

BTW: for whatever reason, this code won't work in the playground. Maybe I'm asking too much of the system.

```
import Foundation

class Gonkulator
{
    var years:Int
    var months:Int
    var days:Int

    init ( inStartDate:NSDate, inNowDate:NSDate )
    {
        // The reason for all this wackiness, is we want to completely strip out the time element of each date. We want the days to be specified at noon.
        var fromString:String = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate ( inStartDate, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle )
        var toString:String = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate ( inNowDate, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle )

        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle

        // We have stripped out the time information, and each day is at noon.
        var startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString ( fromString ).dateByAddingTimeInterval ( 43200 )    // Make it Noon, Numbah One.
        var stopDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString ( toString ).dateByAddingTimeInterval ( 43200 )

        // Get the Gregorian calendar
        let myCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar ( calendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar )

        // Create our answer from the components of the result.
        var components = myCalendar.components ( NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: stopDate, options: nil )
        self.years = components.year
        self.months = components.month
        self.days = components.day

//        DEBUG DISPLAY
//        fromString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate ( startDate, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle )
//        toString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate ( stopDate, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle )
//        println ( "Start Date: " + fromString + " -Years: \(self.years), Months: \(self.months), Days: \(self.days)" )
//        println ( "End Date: " + toString )
    }
}

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle

var startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString ( "12/30/12" ).dateByAddingTimeInterval ( 43200 )    // Make it Noon, Numbah One.
var stopDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString ( "06/30/14" ).dateByAddingTimeInterval ( 43200 )

// First create an instance for December 30, 18 months ago
let test = Gonkulator ( inStartDate: startDate, inNowDate: stopDate )
var years = test.years      // This will be 1
var months = test.months    // This will be 6
var days = test.days        // This will be 0

startDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString ( "12/31/12" ).dateByAddingTimeInterval ( 43200 )

// Next, create an instance for December 31
let test2 = Gonkulator ( inStartDate: startDate, inNowDate: stopDate )
years = test2.years      // This will be 1
months = test2.months    // This will be 6 #WhiskeyTangoFoxtrot
days = test2.days        // This will be 0 #WhiskeyTangoFoxtrot
```

The first call is verified as: [One year and six months](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=12&d1=30&y1=2012&m2=6&d2=30&y2=2014)

The second instance should be [One year, five months and thirty days](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=12&d1=31&y1=2012&m2=6&d2=30&y2=2014)

Comment: Your problem is that you think the Gregorian calendar should be logical and uniform.  For instance, how long, precisely, is a month?

Comment: You have a point (We should all use the Aztec calendar, and observe sacrificial rites on cardinal dates).

Comment: However, note the links that I just added this morning. They give the expected result. I did file this as a Radar issue, but I REALLY don't like blaming the OS or tools (but it's actually kind of likely, as a lot of this stuff is still unripe).

Comment: From the end of month 1 to the end of month 4 is 3 months.  From the 30th of month 1 to the 30th of month 4 is also 3 months.  It seems logical to me -- the best logic you can make from a nonsensical situation.  There is no single "right" answer for this, so one must pick a rule that seems the least arbitrary and stick with it, even though some apparent nonsense will result.  Different designers may pick slightly different rules.

Comment: Thanks. It isn't really that big an issue, as it only seems to happen in rare instances. However, I have the kind of users that will give me grief over this. Just doing my due diligence, so I can tell them that their concern is noted.

Comment: Check dateFormatString, you may be using YY instead of yy and this *may* cause some troubles.